# Is there any Template Haskell tutorial for someone who doesn't know Lisp?

Tags: haskell, macros, metaprogramming, template-haskell

I wanted to learn Template Haskell but all tutorials I find either assume that you learned lisp and know what lisp macros are, or that you know some cs theory jargon - things as splices, quasiquotations, etc... - or some theoretical results about macros.

I can't code a single line of lisp (and, though I intend to do this some day, I don't have the time to learn it right now). Haskell is my very first functional language and I learned it to the point that I can regularly code in it, use monads, applicative, understand the type system, etc...  but I don't know much (also want to learn but I'm too stupid for it... :P) about the theoretical cs stuff behind it. So I'm oblivious to the jargon I typically find on TH tutorials.

So, the question is: is there a tutorial about TH for someone who code Haskell, not as a professional computer scientist, but just as a guy who uses programming for his daily chores, who learned Haskell as his first functional language? Maybe a introduction to macros and meta-programming that use TH as example?

Thanks all. :)

Comment: Actually 'splicing' is just a TH way of saying "code generation" and 'quasiquotation' roughly corresponds to "code parsing". Nothing scary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, I don't think there are any great introductory tutorials to [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell). The best way to learn is to look at examples, or:

- [First stab at Template Haskell](http://www.hyperedsoftware.com/blog/entries/first-stab-th.html)
- [The user's manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html)
- [Igloo's paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ian.lynagh/Template_Haskell/Template_Haskell-A_Report_From_The_Field.ps.gz) :: PS

I never found Lisp was a requirement,  however there is terminology to learn, like for any domain-specific library.

Answer (score 7):

The best introductory tutorials to Template Haskell I know of are two documents by Bulat Ziganshin.  The links from the Haskell Wiki seem to be broken at the moment, however you can access them via archive.org:

- [TH Tutorial](http://replay.web.archive.org/20090421010040/http://www.haskell.org/bz/th3.htm)
- [TH Documentation explanation](http://replay.web.archive.org/20090418034412/http://www.haskell.org/bz/thdoc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Also the original paper [Template metaprogramming for Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/meta-haskell/) by Tim Sheard and Simon Peyton Jones might be helpful:

> **Abstract**
>
> We propose a new extension to the purely functional programming language Haskell that supports compile-time meta-programming. The purpose of the system is to support the algorithmic construction of programs at compile-time.
>
> The ability to generate code at compile time allows the programmer to implement such features as polytypic programs, macro-like expansion, user directed optimization (such as inlining), and the generation of supporting data structures and functions from existing data structures and functions.
>
> Our design is being implemented in the Glasgow Haskell Compiler, ghc.